# PHPDoc for "casted" return type

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have some kind of factory where a method returns one of multiple possible classes but they all inherit the same parent class. The factory method returns always the same class when it gets the same parameter. So when I receive a class from the factory method I know the subclass beside the common parent class.

The problem is that PhpStorm shows me a warning when I try to set the `@return` type to the child class.

Here an example:

```php
abstract class Base {}
class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}

class T {
    /**
     * @param string $class
     * @return Base
     */
    public function returnBase($class)
    {
        switch ($class) {
            case 'A':
                return new A();
                break;
            // ... more cases ...
            default:
                return new B();
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return A
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->returnBase('A'); // Warning: "Return value is expected to be 'A', 'Base' returned"
    }
}
```

I know in this example I could set the return type of `returnBase()` to `A|B`, but in my actual code I have much more classes. I don't want to set the return type of the `test()` method to "Base" because the subclass might have unique methods/properties.

Comment: what happens (in php storm) when you remove the comment about function returnBase returning 'Base'?

Comment: You can avoid the error suggestion by setting `returnBase` to `@return mixed|Base` Additionally I suggest using an Interface instead of an abstract object as the return type checking. This will ensure your returned objects conform to the Interface, where the abstract object and those extending it would need to meet the definitions within the Interface.

Comment: Here's an example of my suggestion and the [result of mixed](http://i.imgur.com/MmBCHP1.png) Also you don't need to break if you return within the switch case.

Comment: PHPDoc cannot help here. Just use `mixed` or perhaps `Object`. As for factories functionality -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata -- works fine (used by quite few plugins and libraries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a varibale type for each `returnBase()` method like this :

```
/**
 * @return A
 */
public function test()
{
    /** @var A $a */
    $a =  $this->returnBase('A');
    return $a;
}
```

Accroding to this article about  [PHP’s Garbage Collection](https://www.sitepoint.com/better-understanding-phps-garbage-collection/), a redundant variable doesn't have any impact on memory consumtion.

Comment: I think it's a bit strange that this doesn't produce the same warning, but it works. Unfortunally it's not really easier than just surpressing the warning by adding `/** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */`, at least in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to avoid these warnings: I explicitly check the instance. So, just edit the function test:

```
public function test(): A
{
    $instanceOfA = $this->returnBase('A');
    
    if (!$instanceOfA instanceof A) {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
    
    return $instanceOfA;
}
```

Here's the full code link with PSALM check: https://psalm.dev/r/4e9e8342fa